# How Can I create,send and receive iq packets using smack(java)

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I am connected to server(Xmpp)
but unable to send and receive packets at my psi client

Here is snippet of my code

```java
POSClientIQ posclientiq = new POSClientIQ();
    posclientiq.connectXMPPServer();
    posclientiq.processMessage();
   }

   public void processMessage()
   {  try{

      final  IQ iq1 = new IQ() {
     public String getChildElementXML() {
      return "<iq type='get' from ='sam'><query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'></query></iq>";
    }
  };

  iq1.setType(IQ.Type.GET);
 // PacketCollector collector = connection.createPacketCollector(new PacketIDFilter(iq1.getPacketID()));
  connection.sendPacket(iq1);

  System.out.println("Message send");
```

Answer (score 2):

The getChildElementXML() returns the  tag. If you are using Smack then you don't need to write your own IQ implementation unless it is a custom query. For your case, to query the roster use [RosterPacket](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/packet/RosterPacket.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a custom query and you would like to use your IQ implementation then:

```
final IQ iq = new IQ() {
public String getChildElementXML() { 
return "<query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/>"; // here is your query
//this returns "<iq type='get' from='User@YourServer/Resource' id='info1'> <query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/></iq>";
 }};
// set the type
iq.setType(IQ.Type.GET);
// send the request
connection.sendPacket(iq);
```

As you can see you have here your custom query and you use Smack to set the rest of your IQ e.g. setting the type. Please note that Smack fills the "from" for you based on the JID your are logged into.

Comment: how can i get response of this raw query? i am unable to get any response out of it

Answer (score 0):

```
//To retrieve archive msges from server..

MyCustomIQ iq = new MyCustomIQ();
      iq.setType(IQ.Type.set);
     mConnection.sendIqWithResponseCallback(iq, new PacketListener() {
                @Override
                public void processPacket(Packet packet) throws SmackException.NotConnectedException {
                    Log.i("Send IQ with Response", "****** message " + packet);
                }
            }, new ExceptionCallback() {
                @Override
                public void processException(Exception exception) {
                  exception.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("IO archjieve Exception",""+ exception.getMessage());
                }
            }, 5000);

      mConnection.sendPacket(new Presence(Presence.Type.available));
            PacketTypeFilter filter=new PacketTypeFilter(org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message.class);
            PacketListener myListener=new PacketListener(){
                public void processPacket(Packet packet){
                   if(((Message) packet).getType().equals(Message.Type.chat))
                    {
                        ((Message) packet).getBody();
                    }
                    else if(((Message) packet).getType().equals(Message.Type.normal))
                    {
                        DefaultPacketExtension pacExten=PacketUtil.packetExtensionfromCollection(packet.getExtensions(), "result", "urn:xmpp:mam:0");
                        String strMsg=pacExten.getValue("body");
                    }
                }
            }
             ;
           mConnection.addPacketListener(myListener, filter);


    //My Custom IQ
    class MyCustomIQ extends IQ {

            String token;


            protected MyCustomIQ() {
            super("query","urn:xmpp:mam:0");
            }



            @Override
            protected IQChildElementXmlStringBuilder getIQChildElementBuilder(IQChildElementXmlStringBuilder xml) {
    //  String queryId = prefix + Long.toString(new AtomicLong().incrementAndGet());
                xml.attribute("queryid",queryId);
                xml.rightAngleBracket();
                return xml;
            }


        }


//You may get the response in PacketListerener sometimes so put debug in that also
```

Comment: how can i send for this
<iq type='set' id='123'>
 <push xmlns='p1:push'>
 <keepalive max="30"/>
 <session duration="60"/>
 <body send="all" groupchat="true" from="jid"/>
 <status type="xa">Text Message when in push mode</status>
 <offline>false</offline>
 <notification>
 <type>applepush</type>
 <id>DeviceToken</id>
 </notification>
 <appid>application1</appid>
 </push>
</iq>